# Set Focus on an Excel User Form Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-controls

I got my project 95% done but a small issue remains. My code, run from a user form, opens a PDF document with its first line, identifies its window in the second and moves and resizes that window in the third.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Mail(0) & Mail(Me.Tag)
    Wnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, AcrobatWindowID(Mail(Me.Tag)))
    SetWindowPos Wnd, HWND_TOP, 1950, 10, 1100, 1300, SWP_NOACTIVATE
```

At the end of this operation the user form is dimmed out. The focus seems to remain with the PDF. That doesn't really matter because the form is fully developed and I can click on it or the PDF to activate either, just the way I wanted.

Nevertheless I tried to give the focus to the form and then to a particular control. I succeeded in finding the Excel window but failed to set the focus on the form, not to mention the control. In fact, I don't know how to check if I succeeded in setting the focus on the Excel window. I used this code in my attempt of whose syntax I'm not sure.

```
Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2           ' ignore cx and cy
Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1           ' ignore X and Y

SetWindowPos Wnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, (SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE)
```

Anyway, the form remains dimmed out. Does anyone have advice for me?

Comment: Would you like doing that from where? From the form in discussion? If yes, when? VBA does not wait for what follows after  `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ...`. I am asking that in order to know what to be used in order to set focus to the window. You can catch the form window handle when it is loaded...

Comment: I meant, you can use `ShowWindow` API, followed by `SetForegroundWindow`. If you want focusing it from another place, you can obtain the necessary handle using also `FindWindow` based on the form Title.

Comment: I have both windows, side by side, both clickable, both functioning. The next step will be a click in the form, which I can do. The click will be on an arrow of a combo box, which also functions. My concern is purely visual: The form's name is dimmed. `ShowWindow` shouldn't be my problem since both windows are shown.`SetForeGroundWindow` might do the job but so should `SetWndowPos` which I did try. It seems to me that the form is in its own window and no activated when the Excel window comes to the fore. Is the form a child winbdow of Excel? Do you know how to get a handle on it?

Comment: No, the form is not an Excel child window... In order to obtain each form handle you should create two `Public` variables in a **standard module**. Let us say `Public frm1Hwnd as LongPtr, frm2Hwnd as LongPtr`. Then, on each form Initialize event, you should have `frmXHwnd = GetActiveWindow`, using API declaration `Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr`. If both forms do not belong to the same workbook you can create function do deliver it, or you may keep the handler even in Registry (converted as long) and reconverting it using `CLngPtr()`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I shall try this in the morning.

Comment: **My** morning passed about eight hours ago... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru That worked like a charm :-) Thanks a million! Please work out an answer and I'l accept it. Note, however, that there is only one user form. The other window is the PDF. The other thing, despite your insistence I created the variable `frmHwnd` in the form's code module with private scope because that's all that's needed. Is there an ulterior, perhaps elementary, consideration in your advice that I may fail to take into account?

Comment: Of course it should  be created (`As Private`) at the form module level. I made that recommendation because I misunderstood the meaning of "I have both windows, side by side". I was thinking of two forms... Only because of that I suggested to make a `Public` variable in a standard module. It should be easy to access from each (ipotetic) form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain the form handler, you should proceed in this way:

1. Use API `GetActiveWindow` and create a `Private` variable on top of the form code module (in the declarations area):

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr

Private frmHwnd as LongPtr
```

2. Insert the next code line in the `UserForm_Initialize` event:

```
frmHwnd = GetActiveWindow
```